# Редактирование элементов gui

Tags: c++, windows

Всем привет! Для написания своих программ использую Visual Studio + чистый WINAPI. Все хорошо и все устраивает, компилируешь программу - запускается везде (от Windows XP до Windows 10) без всяких, дополнительных библиотек. В общем один .exe файл и все...

Тут у меня программа, где достаточно много окон и очень много элементов в этих окнах... Тут просто можно застрелиться. Каждый из них расставлять по своим координатам, очень долго и муторно, потом каждому из них задавать свои свойства, свои стили... А потом, через неделю понять, что сюда, прямо в середину нужно ещё что-то добавить и все это заново двигать... В общем нервов моих на этот не хватает...

Начал искать к этому другой подход и другие IDE. Так то мне понравилось, выносишь на форму кнопочку и в свойствах задаешь ей что угодно, главное все быстро, потом если надо, все это красиво пододвинул, что нужно добавил - класс! Но там другая проблема открылась, рядом с .exe файлом нужно носить дополнительные .dll файлы. Или, что мне рядом своей программой носить установщик Net Framework или ещё что-то. Да и ещё эти .dll подключают все что надо и не надо. Мне WINAPI за то и нравился, что для его работы ничего больше и не надо.

Хотелось бы узнать мнение, либо дальше садомазохизмом с координатами заниматься, либо .dll к программе прилагать?)))))

Comment: ну так в студии есть встроенный редактор диалоговых окон. Также можно найти десятки других - тот же Resource Hacker или Pelles C.

Answer (score 0):

Если будете продолжать дальше программировать, то обязательно столкнётесь с необходимостью запускать свои приложения и под MacOS и в линуксах. Поэтому рекомендую сразу переходить на кроссплатформенные решения, такие как [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/). В обоих двух есть возможность и "рисовать" формы, и генерировать их из кода. Все компоненты - объекты. Всё достаточно просто и удобно.

Ну и если решитесь переходить в Qt, то ваша IDE - [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools)